# Class to simplify skipping some actions on the first loop iteration

Tags: java, android

Often I have to skip some actions on the first (or last) loop iteration. Now I need to append some arguments to a URL and separate the arguments by the `&` character.

For example:

```
http://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/weather?q=London&mode=xml&cnt=7
```

To do so, the code looks like this:

```
public static String prepareUrl(String url, List<? extends NameValuePair> arguments) {
    boolean firstIteration = true;
    StringBuilder urlBuilder = new StringBuilder(url);
    for (NameValuePair argument : arguments) {
        if (firstIteration) {
            firstIteration = false;
        } else {
            urlBuilder.append("&");
        }
        urlBuilder.append(argument.getName());
        urlBuilder.append("=");
        urlBuilder.append(argument.getValue());
    }
    return urlBuilder.toString();
}
```

But it's very annoying to write and a little difficult to read such code. And it's easy to make a mistake in a loop body like this.

I wrote the next class, but I need your help to name the class and its methods properly (I'm pretty bad in English). And please, criticize my code severely.

```
// I know that class name must be a noun.
// But I can't think of a good name.
// And it seems to me that a comparison with the blank cartridge is a good one.
public abstract class FirstCartridgeIsBlank implements Runnable {

    private boolean firstCartridge;

    public FirstCartridgeIsBlank() {
        firstCartridge = true;
    }

    public final void run() {
        if (firstCartridge) {
            firstCartridge = false;
            blankShot();
        } else {
            shot();
        }
    }

    protected void blankShot() {
        // the inheritors can override this method if they need
    }

    protected abstract void shot();

}
```

Now the method `prepareUrl()` looks like this:

```
public static String prepareUrl(String url, List<? extends NameValuePair> arguments) {
    final StringBuilder urlBuilder = new StringBuilder(url);
    FirstCartridgeIsBlank appendAmpersand = new FirstCartridgeIsBlank() {
        @Override
        protected void shot() {
            urlBuilder.append("&");
        }
    };
    for (NameValuePair argument : arguments) {
        appendAmpersand.run();
        urlBuilder.append(argument.getName());
        urlBuilder.append("=");
        urlBuilder.append(argument.getValue());
    }
    return urlBuilder.toString();
}
```

I can't use the `String.join()` method from Java 8 because it's for the Android app (i.e. Java 6).

Comment: Related: [Removing last comma problem](http://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/1973/remove-last-comma-problem)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Don't try to over-generalize early. This is a situation I've run into quite a few times for strings, but never anywhere else, so I would recommend you start with a string-specific solution, and only try to come up with something more general if it ever becomes necessary.

You mention `String.join`- is there any situation where you face this problem where `String.join` wouldn't solve your problem? It's quite possible that the problem you actually need to solve isn't "skipping some actions on the first loop iteration", it's "cleanly joining strings with a separator". If that's the case, then why not just reimplement `String.join` yourself, rather than creating your own very different way of achieving the same thing?

If you *do* need to generalize, then your solution could work, but its main problem is that now you're creating a class whose only purpose is to run a chunk of some arbitrary (possible private!) procedure, just because that chunk happened to follow a particular structure. If Java 6 supported functional programming, then a single class which was passed functions would have been acceptable, but the need to create a new class that inherits from `FirstCartridgeIsBlank` every time you want to use it seems like a design headache to me.

So I think instead of trying to create a class for this, it'd probably just be simpler to do it by extracting methods:

```
public static String prepareUrl(String url, List<? extends NameValuePair> arguments) {
    boolean firstIteration = true;
    StringBuilder urlBuilder = new StringBuilder(url);
    for (NameValuePair argument : arguments) {
        String argumentString = getQueryArgument(argument.getName(), argument.getValue(), firstIteration);
        firstIteration = false;
    }

    return urlBuilder.toString();
}

private static String getQueryArgument(String name, String value, Boolean includeSeparator) {
    //...
}
```

Comment: Excellent answer, don't think I could have said it better myself.

Answer (score 6):

So, you have probably heard that *code duplication is bad*, right? And that led you to want to abstractify this and make it a class?

I fear that this might be a case of [German Overengineering (TM)](https://codereview.meta.stackexchange.com/a/2520/31562) (no offense if you are german).

You have received a good answer by [@Ben](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/users/37788/ben-aaronson) but I'd like to extend a bit on that.

---

#### Composition over inheritance

Is it really necessary to *extend a class* to use these features? Wouldn't it just be easier to copy the code-pattern?

I don't think inheritance is necessary here, it would be better to supply two instances of `Runnable` here, one for the first iteration and one for the other iterations. This would also make it more easier to use for those who have Java 8 available.

Why does your current abstract class implement `Runnable`? Would you pass this to a thread? Would you pass it to any other method that requires a `Runnable`? I would not implement `Runnable`, and also consider naming your method something else, possibly `iterate()`

As shown by your `prepareUrl` implementation, it actually requires *more* code to *use* your class than to just copy the behavior that it does into the code.

About the naming of your method...

```
// I know that class name must be a noun.
// But I can't think of a good name.
// And it seems to me that a comparison with the blank cartridge is a good one.
public abstract class FirstCartridgeIsBlank implements Runnable {
```

A name that popped into my head was `FirstIterationSpecializer` or `DoOnFirstIterationPerformer`. Now especially that second name is really horrible, and would be better as `doOnFirstIteration`, which does sound more like a method than a class. So perhaps the reason why you haven't come up with a good name is that it's not really a good class?

Comment: Good answer, especially the part about how difficulty with naming indicates a problem with the design.

Answer (score 4):

No need to reinvent the wheel here. Just use the Uri.Builder class:

```
String url = "http://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/weather";
Uri.Builder builder = Uri.parse(url).buildUpon();

for(NameValuePair pair : pairs) {
    builder.appendQueryParameter(pair.getName(), pair.getValue());
}

return builder.toString();
```

Comment: Thanks for help. But building `url` is only one of examples of such a loop iteration. I mean - _"to skip the first loop iteration"_ in general

Comment: I didn't even know that `Uri.Builder` existed and had a method for this, I just learned something new!

Answer (score 0):

Disclaimer: not a Java expert here.

Could you do it with an Iterator? Something like this:

```
ListIterator<Thing> it = list.listIterator();

// do something with first item
Thing t = it.next();

t.blankShot();

while ( it.hasNext() ) {
    t = it.next();
    // do something else
    t.shoot();
}
```

Comment: The `blankShot`/`shoot` methods shouldn't be part of the `Thing`, it should rather be `blankShot(t)`. Other than that, your answer is quite similar to other previous answers. And also, if the list contains no elements, your current code will throw an exception.